# installing asp.net 4.5 on IIS 8 on Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-8, iis-8

I just installed windows 8 enterprise edition and I am trying to install IIS before installing VS, I was able to install IIS without asp.net, but when I choose to install ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.NET 3.5 I get this message:

```
Windows needs files from windows update to finish installing some features.
```

First, I would like to know why the installer is asking for this, in previous version the installation of IIS didn't need an internet connection.

Second, I there is not option than download the package, is there any source available to download it in order to install it on computers that doesn't have an internet connection?

thanks.

Comment: It seems that Microsoft moved some of the Windows features out of the installation media, requiring you to download it from the internet, the .NET Framework is one of this, and that's why you're asked to download some files. I'm not aware of a downloadable package that contains these features, but you may look at the Download Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you select to install asp.net 4.5 and asp.net 3.5 at the same time, the first one doesn't have any problem to install.

IF you want to install both, then you have to install framework 3.5 first. These all the instructions.

1. Create a folder in c: called net35.
2. Copy from the installation disk :\sources\sxs all the files to the folder in step 1.
3. Remember to disable the firewall.
4. Run command prompt with administration privileges.
5. Type the following Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:c:\net35 /LimitAccess

Enjoy 3.5 in your windows 8, install both asp.net after this.